# Turn an existing USB into a virtual USB for OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, usb, virtual-machine, osx-yosemite

To use the application TVPaint you are required to have the USB, that it's paired with, plugged into to the computer at all times during use.

For my own convenience and to not risk losing the USB, I want to know if I could turn the USB into a virtual USB on my Mac (OS X Yosemite), ideally tricking the application into thinking the USB is plugged in and allowing the application to work as normal.

Is this possible?

Alternatively, could I duplicate this usb somehow? It'd be great to lower the risk of losing it if I had a spare somewhere else.

Edit: the USB in question is a Safenet dongle

Answer (score 0):

If you could duplicate or bypass a USB security dongle so easily, what would be the point of them?

Some security systems have additional software key capability.

From [SafeNet](http://www.safenet-inc.com/software-monetization/sentinel-hl/)

> Sentinel LDK features unique Cross-Locking technology and is the only software licensing solution on the market to offer hardware- (USB dongles) and software-based protection and secure software licensing in a single solution with one set of tools.

It would appear from [TVPaint's FAQ](http://www.tvpaint.com/v2/content/article/support/faq_qa_display.php?category=30) that they don't have that as an alternative, their licensing model is hardware only.

> *Does the dongle always have to be plugged into the computer to run TVPaint Animation ?*
>   Yes and take care not to disconnect the dongle while the software is in use. However, you can use the dongle on any workstation that has TVPaint Animation installed - but not simultaneously.